# How set useAvroLogicalTypes in an airflow job in GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator?

Tags: avro, airflow

I want to load an avro file to BQ without specifying the schema since BQ does auto schema detection for avro files. However it doesn't pick up logicaltype and converts it to integer. I saw a PR that is merged in Airflow BQ hook but I don't know how to enable that in my job. Is taht a param I need to add to here?

```html
load_transformed_data = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id="gcs_to_bq",
    bucket="mybucket",
    source_objects=["myfile.avro"], 
    destination_project_dataset_table="dataset.test_schema_object", 
    source_format="avro",
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it via **src_fmt_configs** param to GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator whose value is a dict like:
**{'useAvroLogicalTypes': True}**

Your code will be:

```
load_transformed_data = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
  task_id="gcs_to_bq",
  bucket="mybucket",
  source_objects=["myfile.avro"], 
  destination_project_dataset_table="dataset.test_schema_object", 
  source_format="avro",
  write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
  src_fmt_configs={'useAvroLogicalTypes': True},
  dag=dag,
)
```